# Flutter countdown deadline audio

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently working on a Flutter project and utilizing the circular_countdown_timer package to display a countdown timer. However, I am facing a challenge in implementing a feature where I want to play a "Tic" audio during the last 5 seconds of the countdown. Specifically, I would like to play a "Tic" audio for each last second of the countdown, summing up to a total of 5 "Tic" sounds.

I am seeking guidance on how to achieve this functionality within my Flutter application. How can I trigger the audio playback during the last 5 seconds of the countdown, ensuring that the "Tic" audio is played for each last second that counts down?

Any insights, suggestions, or code samples related to integrating audio playback during the countdown using the circular_countdown_timer package would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your support and expertise in resolving this challenge.

Widget:

```
 /// Returns Body as per mode or mode conditions
  Widget returnSmQuizBodyWidget({required BuildContext context}) {
    if (_soloModeLogic.currentMode == 'Exclusive'{
      return const SMWinScreen();
    } else {
      return Column(
        children: [
          //-----------------------   Question Container
          Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [
              //-----------------------   Question Frame
              returnQuestionFrame(context: context),

              //-----------------------   Timer
              Positioned(
                      right: 0,
                      left: 0,
                      bottom: -25,
                      child: CircularCountDownTimer(
                        duration: _soloModeLogic.quizTime,
                        initialDuration: 0,
                        controller: _soloModeLogic.countDownController,
                        width: 5.w,
                        height: 7.h,
                        ringColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
                        ringGradient: null,
                        fillColor: _soloModeLogic.isFreezeColor
                            ? Colors.lightBlueAccent
                            : Colors.red,
                        fillGradient: null,
                        backgroundColor: const Color(0xfff5f5f5),
                        backgroundGradient: null,
                        strokeWidth: 4.w,
                        strokeCap: StrokeCap.butt,
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.sp,
                          color: _soloModeLogic.isFreezeColor
                              ? Colors.lightBlueAccent
                              : Colors.red,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                        textFormat: CountdownTextFormat.S,
                        isReverse: true,
                        isReverseAnimation: false,
                        isTimerTextShown: true,
                        autoStart: true,
                        onStart: () {},
                        onChange: (v) {},
                        onComplete: () =>
                            _soloModeLogic.onTimeOut(context: context),
                      ),
                    ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hey there! Where do you do the computation for counting down to 0? Just from the code, it looks like the countdown is handled in `_soloModeLogic.countDownController`. Is that correct? Could you provide he code for the actual counting down?

Comment: Okay I just went to the actual package site, and it seems the `_soloModeLogic.countDownController` is just controls for the timer haha. Anyways, I can see that the `duration` param is the total time in seconds for the timer right? I'm going to add an answer. Have a look in 5 mins :)

Comment: Yess countDownCoontroller just controllers the countdown. @SafwanParkar

Comment: Just added an answer. Please look and let me know if it makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a [demo app](https://github.com/mearaj/solution_76450197).
based on your code.
It does what you need.
One important thing I came to realize is that during the last five seconds, instead of playing/doing pause each second, which causes sync loss between counter and audio player, start playing audio from the last 5th second and stop at or before zero and select suitable audio file that takes appx 1 second to play a sound.
You can change the audio speed to adjust and you can also look out for alternate audio player library.
You can do anything with the code.(Fork/copy-pase,etc)
Thanks :)

**Edit :**
I realized that in future, I may delete the app from the repo, hence pasting important parts of the code here.
I have `assets/tick.mp3` file in the root directory.
This is my `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
name: solution_76450197
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.3 <4.0.0'
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  circular_countdown_timer: ^0.2.3
  audioplayers: ^4.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/
```

This is my main.dart file.

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:circular_countdown_timer/circular_countdown_timer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class SoloModeLogic {
  String currentMode = "none";
  bool isFreezeColor = false;

  final audioPlayer = AudioPlayer()..setSource(AssetSource('tick.mp3'));
  int quizTime = 10;
  final CountDownController countDownController = CountDownController();


  // The length indicates threshold seconds (last five seconds)
  List<bool> threshold = [false, false ,false,false,false];

  onTimeOut({required BuildContext context}) {
    print("time out");
    audioPlayer.pause();
    //restartCountdown();
  }
  // Please not that it's not called at every second change but instead
  // called on more smaller unit of second second.
  // Hence it could be called multiple times per second
  void onCountdownChange(String v) {
    int vInt = int.parse(v);
    if (vInt > 0 && vInt < threshold.length + 1 && !threshold[vInt-1]) {
      audioPlayer.pause();
      threshold[vInt-1] = true;
      audioPlayer.seek(const Duration(milliseconds: 0));
      audioPlayer.resume();
    } else if (vInt == 0) {
      audioPlayer.pause();
    }
  }


  void restartCountdown() {
    audioPlayer.pause();
    threshold = threshold.map((e) => false).toList();
    countDownController.restart(duration: quizTime);
  }
}

final _soloModeLogic = SoloModeLogic();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return returnSmQuizBodyWidget(context: context);
  }

  /// Returns Body as per mode or mode conditions
  Widget returnSmQuizBodyWidget({required BuildContext context}) {
    if (_soloModeLogic.currentMode == 'Exclusive') {
      return const Text("Exclusive Mode");
    } else {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          //-----------------------   Question Container
          Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [
              //-----------------------   Question Frame
              const Text("My Question"),

              //-----------------------   Timer
              Positioned(
                right: 0,
                left: 0,
                top: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2),
                child: CircularCountDownTimer(
                  duration: _soloModeLogic.quizTime,
                  initialDuration: 0,
                  controller: _soloModeLogic.countDownController,
                  width: 50,
                  height: 70,
                  ringColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
                  ringGradient: null,
                  fillColor: _soloModeLogic.isFreezeColor
                      ? Colors.lightBlueAccent
                      : Colors.red,
                  fillGradient: null,
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xfff5f5f5),
                  backgroundGradient: null,
                  strokeWidth: 4,
                  strokeCap: StrokeCap.butt,
                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: _soloModeLogic.isFreezeColor
                        ? Colors.lightBlueAccent
                        : Colors.red,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                  textFormat: CountdownTextFormat.S,
                  isReverse: true,
                  isReverseAnimation: false,
                  isTimerTextShown: true,
                  autoStart: false,
                  onStart: () {},
                  onChange: _soloModeLogic.onCountdownChange,
                  onComplete: () => _soloModeLogic.onTimeOut(context: context),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _soloModeLogic.restartCountdown();
            },
            child: Text("Start"),
          ),
          // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
        ],
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Mearaj, I'm not using a stateful widget for Countdown. I'm returning it with a function. I have updated the code; please check. Apologies for the late update. @Mearaj

Comment: Np, It's fine. I have updated the answer. @RajA

Comment: Thank you brother. Also onTap() if the countdown is restarted it kinda doesn't work. Any solution for that? @Mearaj

Comment: Hi @RajA, I have fixed that and updated the repo and answer. It happened because I accidentally commented out audioPlayer.seek(const Duration(milliseconds: 0)); during testing. It should work now. Also you may try moving it inside restartCountdown if it's not smooth.

Comment: For some reason, while testing on an Android device, I noticed the tick sound plays only once and then stops, but on the iOS simulator, it works well. @Mearaj

Comment: You can try experimenting with it, like removing audioPlayer.resume() and audioPlayer.pause() from onCountdownChange. You can also try re-initializing audio player inside restartCountdown. You can also try the audioPlayer.stop() property. If nothing works, then please let me know. @RajA

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/audioplayers/latest/audioplayers/AudioPlayer-class.html
You can also check for release mode for loop behavior. https://pub.dev/documentation/audioplayers/latest/audioplayers/AudioPlayer/setReleaseMode.html

Comment: I did play with it. Also tried to initializing audio player inside the function but I'm getting an error: \^[[31mAudioPlayers Exception: AudioPlayerException(
 AssetSource(path: sfx/tick.mp3), 
 PlatformException(DarwinAudioError, AVPlayerItem.Status.failed on setSourceUrl, null, null)<…> @Mearaj

Comment: Ok. Please file an issue at https://github.com/mearaj/solution_76450197, giving details about on what Android version and device the audio is playing only once. I will most probably fix it. Let's discuss there. It's my repo which is open sourced and public, so no issues. I will update the repo with the solution. @RajA

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to audio handling in Flutter, I always go for the [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) package. It does what's needed with ease.

Your `CircularCountDownTimer` has an `onChange` callback that should be sufficient for your use-case of playing a sound every second, in the last 5 seconds.

**Step 1**
Install the `just_audio` package from here: https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio

**Step 2**
In your `onChange` callback, you should be able to get the current duration (e.g. 23) and compare it to the final value (e.g. 0 if counting down), and if the difference is less than or equal to 4, play an audio. Since I'm not a 100% sure about the working of the countdown timer package, I will use pseudo-code.

```dart
late AudioPlayer player;

void initAudio() {
  player = AudioPlayer();
  await player.setAsset('assets/audio/tic.mp3'); // add whatever audio you have
}

CircularCountDownTimer(
  duration: _soloModeLogic.quizTime,
  initialDuration: 0,
  controller: _soloModeLogic.countDownController,
  width: 5.w,
  height: 7.h,
  ringColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
  ringGradient: null,
  fillColor: _soloModeLogic.countDownController.isPaused
      ? Colors.lightBlueAccent
      : Colors.redAccent,
  fillGradient: null,
  backgroundColor: const Color(0xfff5f5f5),
  backgroundGradient: null,
  strokeWidth: 4.w,
  strokeCap: StrokeCap.butt,
  textStyle: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 20.sp,
    color: _soloModeLogic.countDownController.isPaused
        ? Colors.blueAccent
        : Colors.red,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  ),
  textFormat: CountdownTextFormat.S,
  isReverse: true,
  isReverseAnimation: false,
  isTimerTextShown: true,
  autoStart: true,
  onStart: () {},
  onChange: () {
    // considering you're counting from 0 to _soloModeLogic.quizTime
    player.seek(Duration(second: 0));     // set track position to 0
    if (_soloModeLogic.quizTime - currentDuration <= 4) {   // if duration is in last 5 seconds
      player.play();
    }
    
  },
  onComplete: () =>
      player.stop();
      _soloModeLogic.onTimeOut(context: context),
),
```

I hope this made sense. Feel free to ask anything if you're not sure.

Once again, I'm not sure about how the `currentDuration` will be accessed as I have never used the `circular_countdown_timer` package.

Comment: I want to play the tick audio for every second the counter decrements the value. In total, 5 times. The code you suggested will play audio only once, I guess. @Safwan Parkar

Comment: Is that so? according to the docs, `onChange` is called everytime the countdown changes. So it would get called every second, but would play the audio only if the duration remaining is less than or equal to 5 seconds